# Creating an installer out of pyinstall --onedir program

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I am having my app created by pyinstaller with --onedir flag. I would like to somehow "pack" all these files into a easy to use, and user-friendly installer wizard which will unpack all the data in given directory (example: C:\ProgramFiles\MyProgramName) and will also create a shortcut for that program on a windows desktop.

The problem is that I cannot find any software that will help me with such task.

This has to be done this way as my end users don't have Python installed on their computers and also I would like to avoid sending them all unpacked files and creating a complicated instruction (like .pdf or .doc) where to put these files and how to create a shortcut on their desktop themselves.

Comment: use innosetup to make the installer file.you can also use the --onefile tag